# yo jhipster:docker-compose is not able to discover gateway and microservices on prod setup

Tags: jhipster

I started a week before with jhipster and it is definitely up to the mark and provide great developer experience.

Initial project was created on my local laptop and following this [link](https://jhipster.github.io/docker-compose/#-generating-a-custom-docker-compose-configuration-for-multiple-applications)
I am able to do it successfully, but when I am trying the same command and steps on my production setup, it is not able to discover the gateway and services. I found "microservicePath" in gateway (file .yo-rc.json) and updated it. Still `yo jhipster:docker-compose` is not able to discover service and gateway.

- ls in parent directory:
  `docker-compose  gateway  microservice`
- `yo jhipster:docker-compose` from docker-compose dir:

> > ? Enter the root directory where your applications are located (../)
> >
> > >> No microservice or gateway found in /home/ubuntu/

Please tell if something else also needed to be updated on prod box.

-
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more details: Your directory structure, answer for question `Enter the root directory where your gateway(s) and microservices are located?`

Comment: thanks zhang, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The docker-compose subgen discover JHipster apps by looking for .Yo-rc.json files in all sub-directories of the path that is provided (relative or absolute).
If you have the following folder layout :

- gateway
- microservice
- docker

And running `yo jhipster: docker-compose` in the `docker` folder.
You should enter "../" which is the default (so you can also directly hit enter) and then you will have the option to select both apps using "space".

Comment: I have exactly the same layout, and currently I am doing this only, but unfortunately it is not able to discover gateway and micro services.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Have you tried deleting and recreating the docker directory. Another issue that you might have is that there could be a .Yo-rc.json file in a parent directory (for example your home). This would lead yeoman to believe that you are in this directory instead.